# Partial sum formula for $n^{2}(-3)^{-n}$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I was solving a linear recurrence given by:
$$a_{n}+3a_{n-1}=4n^{2}-2n+2^{n}$$
$$a_{0}=1$$
Here's what I've done:
$$(-3)^{n}b_{n}:=a_{n}$$
Substituting in the first equation:
$$b_{n}-b_{n-1}=4n^{2}(-3)^{-n}-2n(-3)^{-n}+\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}$$
The trouble is to find a telescoping sum for the first term of the formula, which consists essentially of:
$$n^{2}(-3)^{-n}$$
I am able to find the second and the third terms.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 x^k = x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^n x^k\right)$ (and there are simpler methods for this kind of problems...).

Comment: Thanks. But what could be a simpler method to solve the recurrence? Was it unclever to change the variable a to b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the linear recurrence, it is advisable to decompose the RHS as a sum of zero (homogeneous equation), a polynomial and an exponential, and solve separately.

1.
$$a_n+3a_{n-1}=0\iff a_n=(-3)a_{n-1}\iff a_n=(-3)^na_0.$$

2.
$$a_n+3a_{n-1}=4n^2-2n$$ is solved with a quadratic poynomial, such that the leading term is $n^2$, because $n^2+3(n-1)^2=4n^2+\cdots$.

Let $a_n=n^2+an+b$ and

$$n^2+an+b+3(n-1)^2+3a(n-1)+3b=4n^2-2n.$$

By identification, one finds

$$a_n=n^2+n.$$

3.
 $$a_n+3a_{n-1}=2^n$$ is solved with the same exponential, $c2^n$,

$$a_n+3a_{n-1}=c2^n+3c2^{n-1}=2^n\iff c=\frac25.$$